# Complete DataTemplate clickable?

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8, mvvm

I have following DataTemplate for usage within my `phone.LongListSelector` in my XAML view:

```
    <DataTemplate x:Name="myLocationsListTemplate">
        <StackPanel Margin="0,0,0,15">
            <Grid VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="0,0,5,0">
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="120" />
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" TextTrimming="WordEllipsis" Text="{Binding Name}" TextWrapping="NoWrap" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextLargeStyle}" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="0,0,0,22" />
                <Image Grid.Column="0" Width="138" Height="25" Source="/mAppData/stars-3.png" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Margin="0"/>
                <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding DistanceInMeterFormatted, FallbackValue=fallback, TargetNullValue=nullvalue, Mode=OneWay}" TextWrapping="NoWrap" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextSubtleStyle}" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="0,0,-3,20" VerticalAlignment="Bottom"/>
                <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Text="vor 10 min." TextWrapping="NoWrap" Margin="0" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextSubtleStyle}" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Bottom"/>
            </Grid>
            <Grid VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="0,10,0,0">
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <Image Grid.Column="0" Width="100" Height="100" Source="{Binding PreviewImg1}"/>
                <Image Grid.Column="1" Width="100" Height="100" Source="{Binding PreviewImg2}"/>
                <Image Grid.Column="2" Width="100" Height="100" Source="{Binding PreviewImg3}"/>
                <Image Grid.Column="3" Width="100" Height="100" Source="{Binding PreviewImg4}"/>
            </Grid>
        </StackPanel>
    </DataTemplate>
```

Now I want the complete DataTemplate Content made "clickable". Means: If user clicks on a TextBlock or one of the four Images or on whatever displayed in die List, an action should be performed with a databound property (saying the `Name` from the bound data should be given).

Any ideas how to get this working?

Comment: Use selectedIndexchanged event instead of any click event on longlistselector.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you just stick your entire template into a button? You can style the button if needs be to remove any default appearance you don't like. eg.

```
<Style x:Key="BlankButtonStyle" TargetType="ButtonBase">

    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="ButtonBase">
                <ContentPresenter />
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>

    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent" />
</Style>
```

Comment: Sounds like a very good idea. I have now enclosed the `StackPanel` with a `<Button>`. But 2 further questions: Where do I have to put your snippet in the XAML file? And how can I Access in my click Event of the button the bound item?

Comment: The style resource can go anywhere in your resource chain (Every element has a .Resources collection). A style like this can be useful throughout the app, so personally I'd stick it in app.xaml. Buttons have a Command property that can be bound to a command on the viewmodel. I would use this instead of a click event otherwise there's no point using a button, any element can raise a click event

Comment: putting your snippet as it is on my page into `<phone:PhoneApplicationPage.Resources>` the editor says on the `<Setter Property...` for `OverridesDefaultStyle` and `FocusVisualStyle` that the member is not recorgnized.

Comment: Apologies, these are WPF properties that are not in Silverlight. You can probably just remove those lines.

Comment: Thanks. Changed `TargetType` from `ButtonBase` to `Button`, deleted These 2 lines and now everything works fine.